# what the point of first.next.previous in doubly-linked-lists?

Tags: data-structures, doubly-linked-list

While I was trying to implement a doubly-linked-list in java, I saw something weird in the text book, for deleting the first index as shown below:

```
public Link deleteFirst()         
{                              
    Link temp = first;
    if(first.next == null)         
        last = null;                
    else
    first.next.previous = null; //THIS IS WEIRD
    first = first.next;            
    return temp;
}
```

The weird thing to me was this line:

```
    first.next.previous = null
```

I tried to play with the code as shown below:

```
    System.out.println(theList.first.next.Data);
    System.out.println(theList.first.previous.Data);
    System.out.println(theList.first.Data);//they are the same
    System.out.println(theList.first.next.previous.Data);//they are the same

 OUTPUT:
 22
 66
 44
 44
```

the outputs are the same even if commented the line :

```
    first.next.previous = null
```

So my question is, what is the point of that?
I've seen this in a tutorial on the web and in my textbook! I'm seeing it useless, so is it that so or I'm wrong?

Comment: If you don't do that, the new `first` would have a dangling `previous` pointer.

Comment: note that the object that the two names `theList.first` and `theList.first.next.previous` reference is in fact the same, the two names are still different. changing `theList.first` does not change `theList.first.next.previous` so to ensure the first link has no previous element, you set `theList.first` and reset the `previous` of the next first element, which is `theList.first.next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have three elements *a, b, c* in the list. Basically, you have the following pointer arithmetic: *a-b-c, first->a, last->c*. If you try to delete *a*, then you have to drop the link *a-b*. After that, *first* should point to *b*. The delete logic would be:

```
temp = first;
if (first.next == null) // after deleting the first, list becomes empty
    last = null;
else
{
    first.next.previous = null; // remove the link a<-b, so b does not point anymore to a
    first = first.next; // so a->b is dropped
}
```